# I can't call the function in prototype .js. Where am I making a mistake?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

Code:

```
DeCheBX = $('MyDiv').insert(new Element('input', { 'type': 'checkbox', 'id': "Img" + obj[i].Nam, 'value': obj[i].IM, 'onClick': SayHi(id)           }));
                            document.body.appendChild(DeCheBX);
                            DeImg = $('MyDiv').insert(new Element('img', { 'id': "Imgx" + obj[i].Nam, 'src': obj[i].IM }));
                            document.body.appendChild(DeImg);
                        }
                        SayHi = function(x) {
                            try {

                            if($('x').checked == true)
                            {
                                alert("press" + x);
                            }

                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        alert("error");
                    }

                };
```

Comment: Format and comment your code so we know what it's supposed to do.

Comment: i wanted to call like when i click on checkbox it should calll th function 
 obj is json string which i m calling in it.the x would be value of checkbox id on which i have clicked.DecheckBx

Answer (score 1):

1: You should declare your variables `DeCheBX`, `DeImg` and `SayHi` with the `var` keyword.
2: In the example it is unclear where `obj[i]` comes from and what it is. Errors may stem from it being not what you hope.
3: You most certanly don't want to call the function `SayHi` and assign its return value (undefined) to the onclick handler of the `Element` you construct and insert into `'MyDiv'`. The way you are doing things, It'd better be a string like `"SayHi(this);"`.
4: There is an extra `}` after `document.body.appendChild(DeImg);`. It makes this part of your example code invalid.
5: In the function `SayHi` you look at the `checked` property of an element with id 'x'. It seems to me that you'd rather want to use the value of the *x* passed to the function (see 3 above).

Comment: i wanted to call like when i click on checkbox it should call the function related to it

Comment: obj is json string which i m calling in it.the x would be value of checkbox id on which i have clicked.DecheckBx.